# Make a cd run a php website NOT on windows

Tags: linux, macos, webserver, portable-applications, embeddedwebserver

I Have the needs to run a php+sqlite (or mysql...) website from a cd.

For windows I found a nice solution (xampp) but I need to make the cd compatible with osx and linux too!

So I basically want to start a webserver (without having to install it) and then automagically open a browser pointing to the local copy of the website.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

there is xampp for linux but the best way to run in it from cd is to create a executable shell script to deploy and set/unset parameters, launch software and deal with configuration
although you could use html5 alternatives javascript+sqlite.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need php, because the software has to be identical in all environment. So I'll try to deploy xampp on linux.